# How do I catch ArgumentError for my whole app in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

### Environment

- RAILS 3.1
- Ruby 1.9.1

I have tried in the `application_controller` but that doesn't seem to work.

Anything I may be doing wrong?

```
  rescue_from ArgumentError do |exception|
     flash.now[:error] = "Arguments for your request are incorrect"
     #ExceptionNotifier::Notifier.background_exception_notification(exception).deliver if Rails.env.production?
     redirect_to root_url, :alert => exception.message
  end
```

The exceptions I am trying to deal with

```
   A ArgumentError occurred in marketplace#index:

  invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
  .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:104:in `normalize_params'
```

or

```
A ArgumentError occurred in connect#index:

  invalid %-encoding (%u2713)
  .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:46:in `decode_www_form_component'
```

Comment: please post where you `raise ArgumentError`. if it your `raise`ing.

Comment: The 2 errors in your questions seems to be coming from rack middle-ware. They occur in the stack before arriving in the rails app, therefore your application_controller will never be aware about those exceptions. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501451/rescue-from-doesnt-rescue-timeouterror-from-views-or-helpers and maybe this https://github.com/hassox/rack-rescue

Comment: Watch this railscast - http://railscasts.com/episodes/53-handling-exceptions-revised

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for an answer for this, I would refer to this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25842118/697816

in the `application_controller.rb` under

`rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: -> { render_404  }`

add

`rescue_from ArgumentError, with: -> { render_404  }`

which will catch all your `ArgumentError` all over