# Recurrent invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 with Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8, rack

### Environment

- Rails 3.2.11
- Ruby 1.9.1
- `utf8-cleaner` gem

I am struggling with this issue for over a year now, and I am not able to reproduce it on my dev environment, which makes it rather difficult for me to understand why this is happening and how I can resolve. Here is the error notification I am getting (via email using ExceptionNotifier):

```
A ArgumentError occurred in home#index:

  invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
  .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:104:in `normalize_params'
```

Apparently caused by Chinese spider:

```
 HTTP_USER_AGENT      : Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; EasouSpider; +http://www.easou.com/search/spider.html)
```

I have tried to a couple things, see my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24722176/how-do-i-catch-argumenterror-for-my-whole-app-in-rails) where I was attempting to catch the error.

I have also installer `utf8-cleaner` gem but that doesn't seem to resolve, unless I missed a step.

How can I reproduce the issue? Note the URL causing the problem is perfectly correct when I access it (?)

### UPDATE 20140721 - use [rack-utf8_sanitizer](https://github.com/whitequark/rack-utf8_sanitizer)

- Add `gem 'rack-utf8_sanitizer'` in `Gemfile`
- Add `config.middleware.insert 0, Rack::UTF8Sanitizer` in `application.rb`
- `$ bundle install`

That worked perfectly on DEV but FAILED on my Heroku PRODUCTION,  with the following issue:

```
$ heroku run rake middleware --a test-app
Running `rake middleware` attached to terminal... up, run.4846
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.6
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Rack::UTF8Sanitizer
/app/config/application.rb:71:in `<class:Application>'
```

I am still investigating why I should be getting this.

Comment: Don't let the reader read a different page in order to understand your question. Make this question self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Reproduce the issue caused by

```
HTTP_USER_AGENT      : Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; EasouSpider; +http://www.easou.com/search/spider.html)
```

#### Create a ruby script

```
#!ruby
invalid = "data\xed\xe5\xed\xe0".force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT')
`curl localhost:3000 -d #{invalid}`
```

#### Add the [rack-utf8_sanitizer gem](https://github.com/whitequark/rack-utf8_sanitizer) to your Gemfile

This resolved for my Dev environment, but wouldn't work on Heroku. I updated my question accordingly.

UPDATE:

I added require "rack/utf8_sanitizer" in my application.rb file and that seems to resolve, the Heroku issue.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it (on a Rails 3.2.18 app) as described in this gist:

https://gist.github.com/joost/ca4eda8f31655cf6095a